# Change state of one div based on hovering list item within a sibling div

Tags: css

How to influence on element depending on sibling's child state?

```
<div class="root">
    
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li>...</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="main">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Smth like this but it doesn't work:

```
.menu li:hover ~ .main {
  /* change "main" if some <li> is hover */
}
```

Comment: Is this answering your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Comment: because `.main` is not `li` sibling here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem

1: `.root .main` is not a sibling of `.root .menu li`.

2: There isn't a CSS selector currently capable of doing what you're trying to do - [See the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors#combinators). You will need to use a bit javascript/jQuery. Here are a few possible solutions...

#### Solution 1: Classes

**CSS:**

```css
/* Default styling */
.menu {
    background: green;
    color: blue;
}

/* Hovered styling */
.menu.hovered {
    background: purple;
    color: red;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```js
$('.root .menu li').hover(function() {
    $('.root .main').addClass('hovered');
}, function() {
    $('.root .main').removeClass('hovered');
});
```

#### Solution 2: Inline styling

**CSS:**

```css
/* Default styling */
.menu {
    background: green;
    color: blue;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```js
$('.root .menu li').hover(function() {
    $('.root .main').css('background', 'purple');
    $('.root .main').css('color', 'red');
}, function() {
    $('.root .main').attr('style', '');
});
```